# kSecAccessControlUserPresence doesn't launch FaceId on Authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I'm creating Keypair with ACL binding and I used `kSecAccessControlUserPresence` key to assume that it'll first launch TouchID/FaceID and if not register then prompt Passcode and its working fine on iPhone6Plus but on my iPhoneX prompt Passcode even I've registered my Face on FaceID. 
So I've following questions.

- `kSecAccessControlUserPresence` says that It'll first prompt by Bio-metric(TouchId/FaceId) and if not registered any then prompt by Passcode, is this understanding right?
- If my above understanding isn't right then how can I choose Bio-metric first then to push on Passcode ?

Here following is my code.

```
private func generateHardwareKeyPairEC(keypairAttributes : KeyPairAttributes, completionHandler: @escaping (OSStatus?) -> Void ) {
// Access Control List

let accessControl: SecAccessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, [SecAccessControlCreateFlags.privateKeyUsage, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence], nil)!

// Public Key parameters
let publicKeyParams: [String: Any] = [
  kSecAttrLabel as String: keypairAttributes.keyLabel!,
  kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : keypairAttributes.keyApplicationTag!
  ]

// Private Key parameters
let privateKeyParams: [String: Any] = [
  kSecAttrLabel as String: keypairAttributes.keyLabel!,
  kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : keypairAttributes.keyApplicationTag!,
  kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
  kSecAttrAccessControl as String: accessControl,
  ]

//Key Pair parameters
let params: [String: Any] = [
  kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,//key type will be used here
  kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: keypairAttributes.keySize!,
  kSecAttrTokenID as String: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
  kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String : publicKeyParams,
  kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: privateKeyParams
]

//var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { // 1
  let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(params as CFDictionary, &self.publicKey, &self.privateKey)

  if status == noErr {
    print("Private key: \(String(describing: self.privateKey))\nPublic key: \(String(describing: self.publicKey))")
    print("Private key: \(String(describing: self.privateKey))\nPublic key: \(String(describing: self.publicKey))")
    completionHandler(status)
  } else {
    print("Failed to generate key pairs")
    completionHandler(status)
  }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, forgot to add the Face ID Usage Description key to Info.plist.

> In any project that uses biometrics, include the NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in 
>   your app’s Info.plist file. Without this key, the system won’t allow your app to 
>   use Face ID.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id